# Flume twitter stream

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter4j, flume, flume-twitter

I am trying to execute flume to get data from twitter stream but received this error while executing the flume.

> [ERROR - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:253)] Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource{name:Twitter,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V
>       at com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.start(TwitterSource.java:140)
>       at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
>       at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am a beginner to flume and working in Cloudera quickstart. While searching for solutions it was said to install maven and then build the flume-snapshot jar file from there but I don't know how I can install maven in Cloudera quickstart. Any help on how to correct this error please I have been stuck here for 1 week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
The conflict is raised by twitter4j files and flume snapshot jars. So I renamed the twitter4j jars by changing their file extenstion with jarx. Another thing I did by reading from this [article](https://chisqr.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/simple-twitter-sentiment-analytics-using-apache-flume-and-spark-part-1/) is to put flume snapshot in following hierarchy.
/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/plugins.d/flumesnapshot and following same pattern in var directory.